# Infinite set and Permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Suppose $X$ a infinite set and $S_X$ is the permutation group of $X$. Prove that any proper subgroup of $S_X$ has infinite index.

Comment: It helps a lot if you say what you've already tried in proving this and where it didn't work.

Comment: Presumably $s_x$ is the full symmetric group on $x$?

Comment: @Derek Yes, it must be, since the finitary symmetric group on an infinite set admits the alternating subgroup of index two.

Answer (score 2):

The nontrivial normal subgroups of the symmetric group on an infinite set $X$ consist of the finitary alternating and symmetric groups,  together with the groups whose support is bounded above by a fixed infinite cardinality. (See, for example, Dixon & Mortimer, Permutation Groups, Thereom 8.1A.) So all proper normal subgroups have infinite index and hence the same applies to all proper subgroups.